# React keep track of element clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list of items like this:

```
<div className="items-section">
 {items.map((item) => 
   <Item key={item.id} {...item} />
 )}
</div>
```

When user clicks on an item from the list, they will get redirected to `/items/:itemId` url to see that item, when they click to go back or close that modal that will display that item, I want to display the list and focus on the element where they stopped and clicked. How is it working now, 20 items are displayed to the user, they click on the 11th item, then click back and again list is displayed starting from the top page from 1st item. How can I make it to get back to that 11th element for a better experience?

I am using redux as well and I thought to keep track of the element clicked, but how to reflect this in React and display from that element. I thought of `useRef` but I do not see how to use here. Could anyone please suggest me what to do and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can give ids while you are mapping your list. Like this

```
{items.map(item => <div id={`foo-${item.id}`}>foo</div>
```

then whenever you want to select this item you can

```
const foundItem = document.getElementById(`foo-${here is your stored item.id in redux}`)
```

and now you have this node. If you want you can scroll to this node by using scrollTo or if you want give a class.